# Search sequence within %APPDATA%

Tags: exe4j

Does anybody know how to use APPDATA in search sequence to locate folder `c:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\jre\` ?

I try with `%APPDATA%\jre\` and `%EXE4J_APPDATA%\jre\` but without luck.

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: Let me answering to my own question:

search sequence should be: ${USERPROFILE}\AppData\Roaming\jre\